# Need to place assets inside Library folder of an application's Sandbox for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

Generally if an application is build and deployed, In sandbox location four folders will be created which are listed below.
1. Library
2. temp
3. Documents
4. xyz(Application's Root folder name)

But all the resources are placed inside 4th folder by default in **sandbox location**.

Is there any way to place **selected file inside** Library folder or any **other folder** in the above list while building application.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Building an app can only put files in the app's resource bundle. Remember, when a user downloads your app from the store, all they get is the app. When the app is installed, the app's sandbox is created for the first time. But the sandbox is empty except for the app's resource bundle.

If you want files to be put elsewhere in the sandbox, your app needs to copy the files from the resource bundle to the other locations the first time it is run.